# HTML -- Input[TEXT] drop-down with relevant suggestions

Tags: javascript, html

I already know how to design the suggestions from the database/sql standpoint, but I have no idea how to go about the basic design of actually getting the text-field to display a dropdown with suggestions. I would assume the best example of this would be the following link: http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices

In which there is a field that says: "Look up a price". If you start typing, it will poll the database (I'm assuming) and give you a dropdown list. I'm trying to figure out how to do just that.

For simplicity, I'm more than happy with an example using an array that always pops up the same thing, once you start typing.

I've looked this up, and perhaps I'm just looking wrong but I'm at a complete loss, as there's no HTML element (That I can find) that allows you to type into a text-field while it acts as a dropdown box.

Comment: Most modern browsers support the `<datalist>` element for this purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist . For more flexibility and older browser support, try jQuery autocomplete or some other JavaScript-based solution.

Comment: @DCoder - With a database containing over 50,000 items the datalist approach does not seem very viable. I linked the example using a form of auto-complete because I am looking for an example for a similar system, where I can poll the database with a `%LIKE%` query and return 15-20 results. Using the `<datalist>` it seems like I'd need the entire database loaded into the clients browser.

Comment: What's stopping you from modifying the content of the `<datalist>` at runtime using JavaScript?

Comment: There are [*many questions about this already*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dtypeahead+list). Do some research, find an approach that suits then come back when you need further help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an an event listener to the input field:

```
input.addeventlistener('change', function () {
    var response = callServer(),
        arr = JSON.parse(response),
        parentDiv = document.getElementById('list');

    //fill the options in the document
    for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = response[x].someOption;

        //add each autocomplete option to the 'list'
        parentDiv.appendChild(span);
    };

    //show the list with all the spans within it
    parentDiv.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Then, when the input is changed, invoke the `callServer` function which sends an ajax query to a url and returns a JSON object:

```javascript
function callServer () {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            //return the JSON object
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Just return a JSON object from your server ready for javascript to parse. To have the options appear like a 'dropdown', simply create a div element, style the div to be sure it appears below the element, and populate the div with the dynamically created spans.

So the dynamically created HTML would look like:

```html
<div id='list'>
    <span>Some Option 1</span>
    <span>Some Option 2</span>
    <span>Some Option 3</span>
    <span>Some Option 4</span>
</div>
```

The rest of the effects, like `:hover` is done with css. You can also add an `onclick` even to each span to simulate the user selecting that option.

Comment: Good answer, but would be greatly improved without the "we".  Just delete it: `now we show the list` -> `now show the list`. See? ;-)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. Uses pure Javascript, doesn't require any dependencies such as JQuery. +1